# MySQL query that limits first join to specific number of rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query that joins 3 tables and I want to limit the first join to just 5 rows. The end result can return any number of rows so I don't want to add LIMIT to the end of the query.

Here is the query I have, which works but obviously does not limit the first join to 5 rows. I've attempted a subquery, which I believe is the only way to accomplish this, and everything I try gives an error. I can't seem to apply examples I have seen, to my situation.

```
SELECT mw_customer.customer_id, mw_customer.customer_uid, mw_campaign.customer_id, mw_campaign.campaign_id, mw_campaign.type, mw_campaign.status, mw_campaign_delivery_log.campaign_id, mw_campaign_delivery_log.subscriber_id
   FROM mw_customer 
   JOIN mw_campaign
        ON mw_customer.customer_id = mw_campaign.customer_id
        AND mw_customer.customer_uid = 'XYZ'
        AND mw_campaign.type = 'regular'
        AND mw_campaign.status = 'sent'
   JOIN mw_campaign_delivery_log
        ON mw_campaign.campaign_id = mw_campaign_delivery_log.campaign_id
```

So what I want to do is limit the "JOIN mw_customer" to a maximum of 5 rows and then after the JOIN mw_campaign_delivery_log, there can be any number of rows.

Thanks

Comment: provide table structures and example data as ascii data based tables.. also post the excepted result as a ascii data based table.. We are not here to reverse engineer your SQL code.

Comment: Move the first join into a subquery, and use `LIMIT` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the first join in a subquery with `LIMIT 5`.

```
SELECT t.customer_id, t.customer_uid, t.campaign_id, t.type, t.status, l.subscriber_id
   FROM (SELECT cus.customer_id, cus.customer_uid, cam.campaign_id, cam.type, cam.status
         FROM mw_customer AS cus
         JOIN mw_campaign AS cam
            ON cus.customer_id = cam.customer_id
         WHERE cus.customer_uid = 'XYZ'
            AND cam.type = 'regular'
            AND cam.status = 'sent'
         LIMIT 5) AS t
   JOIN mw_campaign_delivery_log AS l
        ON t.campaign_id = l.campaign_id
```

Note that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` means that the 5 rows selected will be unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. However, that gave me an error: "#1060 - Duplicate column name 'customer_id'"

Comment: Need to replace `SELECT *` with selecting specific columns in the subquery.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. That is exactly what I was looking for. I added in the ORDER BY as well, as you suggested.